# Add missing data for specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

Specialty

```
SpecialtyId Name IsEnabled
```

SpecialtyReport

```
UserId SpecialtyName ReportsRead
```

I am trying to figure out how to select all the records for a specific user from SpecialtyReport Table and then whatever Name is missing, populate it from Specialty Table and all other values can be null.

What I have tried is this:

```
SELECT s.Name, t.UserId, t.ReportsRead
FROM Specialty s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecialtyReport t ON s.Name = t.SpecialtyName
WHERE t.UserId = 1
```

However, the result that I get is same as if I did Inner join. The Specialty Table has about 10 rows and all with unique names, where as the SpeialtyReport Table has 3 rows with that User Id.

I can't figure out why the outer left join won't populate missing names. The end result I get from above query is just 3 rows.

EDIT:

The SpecialtyReport Table is made up, it comes from a subquery.  I did a test where I created the actual table and my query works on it, but it doesn't work if I replace the table with results from a subquery. Why is that?

Comment: can you give sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write UserId predicate at join part

```
SELECT s.Name, t.UserId, t.ReportsRead
FROM Specialty s
LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecialtyReport t ON s.Name = t.SpecialtyName
      and  t.UserId = 1
```

Comment: How does this differ from my query? I'm sorry I can't seem to spot the difference.

Comment: I deleted the where part and moved UserId = 1 predicate to join part with and

Comment: use ISNULL(userId,'noid')

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`  functions. for example ISNULL(t.UserId,'')